# Why am frequently asked for access to my Keychain?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, sleep-wake, keychain, screensaver

Since using Migration Assistant to move from an old iMac (2009) to a new MacBook Pro, I find that I'm repeatedly asked for access to my Keychain. Prior to moving to the new machine, once I unlocked my Keychain, I was never asked for access to it again, but now I find that I'm often asked to provide the Keychain password. Sometimes this seems associated with periods of system sleep, but not always.

[image]

At first, I thought this was the result of the Keychain locking during sleep, or perhaps for some other reason so I made sure to adjust the settings for the "login" Keychain (using "Change Settings" in the keychan's context menu) so that it would not lock when the screensaver is on or after inactivity:

[image]

[image]

However this only seems to have been partially effective. In particular, there's no way to make the same adjustment to the "Local Items" Keychain  so that preventing it from locking automatically is beyond my control:

[image]

[image]

How do I ensure that my Keychains remain unlocked once I've unlocked them? Why has this behavior suddenly appeared on my MacBook, when it was not present on my iMac?

Comment: I'm having a [related problem](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/111766/4395) with frequent requests for the password to an already unlocked keychain.

Comment: Maybe that article helps: http://support.apple.com/kb/TS5362

Comment: @codingFriend1: That may be the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Local Items keychain was [introduced on Mavericks](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/10/os-x-10-9/5/) and holds iCloud keys for offline use.

However, sometimes OS X will repeatedly ask you for the password. This can be solved by deleting the folder named with an UUID like `A8F5E7B8-CEC1-4479-A7DF-F23CB076C8B8` from `~/Library/Keychains/` and then reboot. No keys will be lost in this process.

This is described here: http://support.apple.com/kb/TS5362

Comment: The Apple link is dead.

Comment: Apple link available in the Internet archive
https://web.archive.org/web/20150208091616/http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203897